# How does the enterState() Transitions work? (Slick2D)

Tags: java, slick2d

I have seen the transition thing with the enterState() function, but there you can also specify a out and in transition. How does this work?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean, by "how does this work?". Are you asking how to utilize the enter and exit state methods?

Comment: I am asking how to use it and what it does.

Comment: Has my answer helped you or am I still misunderstanding your question? If it helped, it would be nice to accept my answer, otherwise please expand upon what you wish to accomplish with transitions a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The slick2d game state methods of enterState() lets you set a transition between two gamestates. Let's say you have a splashscreen, and a Main Menu, where your New Game/Options/Exit choices reside. If you wish to have a fade effect between the splashscreen to the main menu, as most games tend to have a fade to black transition, you can call this in your update method after a certain time interval has passed in your splashscreen game state:

```
statebasedgame.enterState(*state id you wish to enter*, new FadeOutTransition(), new FadeInTransition());
```

What this is telling the slick engine to do for you, is to fade out (exit effect) which will be a new FadeOutTranstion() class type, switch to the new game state class, and the fade in (enter effect) will be a new FadeInTranstion() class type.

There are a lot of transition effects prebuilt into slick, and just as well, you can even build your own if you want by extending the Transition class.

Good example of a personal made effect: http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1008

More examples of the transition effects that can be used: https://github.com/ariejan/slick2d/blob/master/src/org/newdawn/slick/tests/TransitionTest.java